# How to use _.omit properly

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm attempting to replace a `for` loop with `_.omit`, but can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Here is my (working) `for` loop:

```
  for (var propt in params.filter()) {
    if (params.filter()[propt] === '') {
      delete params.filter()[propt];
    }
  }
```

and here is the underscore code I'm trying to replace it with:

```
_.omit(params.filter(), function(value) {
  return value === '';
});
```

The underscore version does not omit the property with a blank value as I would expect.

Comment: Why does your code repeatedly call `params.filter()`? What does it do, always return the same object? (Why) Do you want to mutate that? How are you going to use it afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Your first version modifies whatever `params.filter()` returns (an object...) and deletes the matching (empty) properties from the object itself.

The second, underscore version, returns a copy of that object with all but the matching properties.

If you can reassign the value, you could use the output from `_.omit(...)` as the new value.

Comment: Ahhh true, thanks. Is there even a way to use `_.omit` in this instance?